# Audio hosting service that offers transcriptions of uploaded file?

Tags: audio, accessibility, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Similar to how YouTube captions videos, is there any audio hosting service out there that will transcribe audio and provide a written transcription for accessibility purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You could upload the audio to YouTube as a video file and get its auto-captions, terrible as they are, then extract those.

You should know that YouTube's auto-captioning should never (*never*) be relied on. You can instead use it to generate a rough time-based set of captions that you can then download and correct.

The easiest way to do that is via [No More Craptions](http://nomorecraptions.com/), which will take a YouTube video with auto-captions and walk you through correcting them in a simple interface.

You may then download your completed work as a transcript as well. When you do that, remember to offer a plain text link near the audio file / player on the page with a clear indication of what the user will receive.

Let me reiterate — *never* rely on YouTube auto-captions. *Always* correct whatever YouTube provides. *Always*.